# Animation paused successfully but not changing opacity

Tags: html, css

I'm not much of a coder myself, I pretty much take codes from the internet and try to fit them on my website. The problem is I've taken a code from somewhere modified it a bit, but it doesn't seem to properly work. Here's the code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;}
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;}
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
    }

.pulseb {
        animation-duration: 5000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    animation-name: flash;
}

.pulseb:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: paused;
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

As you can see, i've added the opacity tag, but it doesn't work. The animation just pauses itself WITHOUT setting the opacity back to 1.0 when hovered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, changed -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-play-state: paused;

to : -webkit-animation: 0;